# Вопрос по webhook

Tags: ip

Всем привет!
Имеется следующий вопрос:
есть в наличии vps на windows server. на нём 2 ip
хочу запустить на нём 8 ботов
знаю что на 1 ip адрес можно сделать 4 бота под порты 80, 88, 443 и 8443.
Сделал самоподписной сертификат на 1й и на 2й ip адреса и поместил их в ботов с настройками по ip эти. в итоге работают только 4. Что может быть? подскажите куда копать???

Comment: Не обязательно на каждого бота выделять отдельный порт. Пусть вебхук ведёт на разную директорию. Пример 127.0.0.1/bot1

Comment: И не нужно делать самоподписанные сертификаты, когда существует Let's Encrypt

Comment: спасибо. а к примеру как должен быть выглядеть запрос если бот к примеру к c:\bot\bot1 ?